# Alternate to np.meshgrid() from python in Julia?

Tags: numpy, julia, mesh

I would like to know, if there is any alternate to the `np.meshgrid()` from NumPy-Python in Julia?

#Python reference : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the example in the Python `meshgrid` manual in Julia you can do:

```
x = 0.0:0.5:1.0   
y = 0.0:1.0

julia> xv = first.(Iterators.product(x,y))
3×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.5  0.5
 1.0  1.0

julia> yv = last.(Iterators.product(x,y))
3×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  1.0
 0.0  1.0
 0.0  1.0
```

These outcomes are transposed (compared to Python) but in Julia, contrary to Python, the first array index is a row and the second is a column (Julia has column-major arrays)

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that in Julia you can usually avoid `meshgrid` using smart broadcast operations. For example. Given a function `f(x, y)` that operates on scalar values and two "vectors" `xs` and `ys`, you can write `f.(xs, ys')` to produce pretty much any result `meshgrid` would give you and more:

```
julia> xs = 0:0.5:1
0.0:0.5:1.0

julia> ys = 0.0:1.0
0.0:1.0:1.0

julia> f(x, y) = (x, y)                # equivalent to meshgrid
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f.(xs, ys')
3×2 Matrix{Tuple{Float64, Float64}}:
 (0.0, 0.0)  (0.0, 1.0)
 (0.5, 0.0)  (0.5, 1.0)
 (1.0, 0.0)  (1.0, 1.0)

julia> g(x, y) = x*y                   # more efficient than meshgrid + product
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g.(xs, ys')
3×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.5
 0.0  1.0
```